# Changing permission of a file in Android for fopen

Tags: android, c, permissions, fopen, arm64

I am trying to use `fopen` to open a file and write logs in it and save it back to the device, but I can't seem to `fopen` and `strerror` returns `error 22`:
The suggested location was `/data`. I did a bit of search here and found out that a better location is at `/mnt/sdcard`, say `Download`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
        //writing to a file
        FILE * fp;
        fp = fopen("logmsg.txt", "+wb");
        if (fp != NULL) {
                 fprintf(fp,"File created successfully!\n");
                 printf("File created successfully!\n");
        }
        else {
                printf("Failed to create the file.\n");
                printf( "Error code opening file: %d\n", errno );
                printf( "Error opening file: %s\n", strerror( errno ) );
        return -1;
        }
return 0;
}
```

However, I don't seem to be able to change permissions using `chmod` and it returns no error. Is `/mnt` mounted noExec? Any workaround is appreciated.

Some info:

```
Kernel: 3.18.31-g3d35637
CPU HW: Qualcomm Technologies, Inc APQ8096
Processor       : AArch64 Processor rev 2 (aarch64)
```

**Update-1**: 
After the suggestions from @kiran to change `+w` to `w+`, I have `error 30` as `Read-only file system` on `\data` and `Permission Denied` on `/mnt/sdcard/Download`. How do I overcome this issue?

**Update-2: Quick Workaround**: 
What I did was to `adb shell mount -o rw` and I was able to save my file

Answer (score 3):

According to [errno.h](http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno) errno 22 is

**#define EINVAL      22  /* Invalid argument */**

Means  you are passing invalid argument for `fopen`.

```
   fp = fopen("logmsg.txt", "+wb");
```

should be

```
   fp = fopen("logmsg.txt", "wb+");
```

According to  [fopen-man-page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen)

*The argument mode points to a string beginning with one of the following sequences (possibly followed by additional characters, as described below):*

> **r**
>
> *Open text file for reading. The stream is positioned at the
>   beginning of the file.*
>
> **r+**
>
> *Open for reading and writing. The stream is positioned at the
>   beginning of the file.*
>
> **w**
>
> *Truncate file to zero length or create text file for writing. The
>   stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.*
>
> **w+**
>
> *Open for reading and writing. The file is created if it does not
>   exist, otherwise it is truncated. The stream is positioned at the
>   beginning of the file.*
>
> **a**
>
> *Open for appending (writing at end of file). The file is created if it
>   does not exist. The stream is positioned at the end of the file.*
>
> **a+**
>
> *Open for reading and appending (writing at end of file). The file is created if it does not exist. The initial file position for reading is at the beginning of the file, but output is always appended to the end of the file.*
>
> *The mode string can also include the letter 'b' either as a last
>   character or as a character between the characters in any of the
>   two-character strings described above.*

Comment: Thanks, @kiran. That effectively alleviate error 22, however, you did not mention how I could resolve the permission issue. Now, I am receiving `error 30` on `/data` and `permission denied` on `/mnt/sdcard/Download`

Comment: What I did was to `adb shell mount -o rw` and I was able to save my file

Comment: @Amir Are you running this program as native service?

Comment: I cross-compiled it using NDK and pushed it using adb push on the device

Answer (score 1):

For part 2, the answer to why you can't write to `/data` is that as the ADB shell account, you don't have write permission for that directory. You don't have nearly as much freedom to use the filesystem in your own way on Android as you do on Linux or Windows.

You do have write permission for `/data/local/tmp`, and you can create yourself a working directory under there. So if, for example, you do this:

```
adb shell "mkdir /data/local/tmp/my_directory"
adb push ./my_executable /data/local/tmp/my_directory
adb shell "cd /data/local/tmp/my_directory ; ./my_executable"
```

That should be able to create the `logmsg.txt` file.